# Starting Bootstrap Accordion with Minus on Active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my bootstrap accordion starting with 1 panel open. I also have added a JS that allows for a + or - to appear when the panel is collapsed or expanded. It works great on the panels that start collapsed, but is backwards for the panel that starts expanded. How can i fix it so that the first panel (active panel) starts with the - rather than the +?

```js
  $('.closeall').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse.in')
      .collapse('hide');
  });
  $('.openall').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
      .collapse('show');
  });

  function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
      .prev('.panel-heading')
      .find(".more-less")
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  }
  $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
  $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

```css
.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.panel-title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.more-less {
  float: right;
  color: #212121;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </a>
                            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                                </a>
                            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                    <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                    Collapsible Group Item #3
                                </a>
                            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- panel-group -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **in** from:

```
div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"
```

and execute on document ready:

```
$('.panel-collapse:first').collapse('show');
```

Snippet:

```js
function toggleIcon(e) {
  var currentPanel = $(e.target).closest('div.panel-default');
  $('div.panel-default').not(currentPanel).find('a[role="button"]').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
  currentPanel.find('a[role="button"]').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
}

$(function () {
  $('.closeall').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
  });
  $('.openall').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
    .collapse('show');
  });

  $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
  $('.panel-collapse:first').collapse('show');
});
```

```css
.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.panel-title {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.panel-title > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.more-less {
  float: right;
  color: #212121;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                Collapsible Group Item #2
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                Collapsible Group Item #3
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- panel-group -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change class of *more-less* item. Replace glyphicon-plus with glyphicon-minus

```
<a role="button" class="accordion-toggle" ...>
    <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
</a>
```